# Inserting into the middle of a list(of integer), and list(of string)

Tags: vb.net-2010

I have the following code:

```
Private Sub highscoreCheck()
    Dim a As Integer, b As String, c As Integer
    For a = 1 To 10
        If highscore > lst_score(a) Then
            highscoreIndex = a
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If highscoreIndex > 0 Then
        For highscoreIndex As Integer = 1 To 10
            b = lst_name(highscoreIndex)
            c = lst_score(highscoreIndex)
            If highscoreIndex = a Then
                lst_name(highscoreIndex) = userName
                lst_score(highscoreIndex) = highscore
            Else
                lst_name(highscoreIndex) = b
                lst_score(highscoreIndex) = c
            End If
        Next

    End If
End Sub
```

I have a highscore list, that consists of 10 lines, and highscoreindex stands for if the current highscore is bigger than any and if is, than the highscoreIndex is the highest number of those. ( like: 12, 8, 6. And the current one is 9, then the highscoreindex is 2).
What I wanted the code to do was to insert the current highscore to the proper position and make the ones that are under it and the one it replaced to go one down. 
It does insert the current highscore, but doesn't make the others go one down, what have I screwed up? What should I do?

Comment: You need to be using [List.Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4.aspx).

Comment: Oh wow, that was a lot easier than I thought, thank you. It works now.

Comment: You are welcome! Always know your tools! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having separate arrays, one for name and one for score, create a **Class** to hold the two associated values.  Make that class implement **IComparable** so they can sort themselves.  Hold instances of your class in a **List()** so you can call **Sort()** against it.  After adding to the List and calling Sort(), repeatedly remove the last entry until you have only the desired number left in left.

Here's a quick example:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Const MaxNumberOfHighScores As Integer = 3
    Private HighScores As New List(Of ScoreEntry)

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim score As New ScoreEntry
        score.Name = "Bob"
        score.Value = 7
        AddEntry(score)

        score = New ScoreEntry
        score.Name = "George"
        score.Value = 3
        AddEntry(score)

        score = New ScoreEntry
        score.Name = "Dora"
        score.Value = 9
        AddEntry(score)

        score = New ScoreEntry
        score.Name = "John"
        score.Value = 6
        AddEntry(score)

        score = New ScoreEntry
        score.Name = "Jennifer"
        score.Value = 10
        AddEntry(score)

        score = New ScoreEntry
        score.Name = "Mike"
        score.Value = 8
        AddEntry(score)

        For i As Integer = 0 To HighScores.Count - 1
            Debug.Print(HighScores(i).Name & ": " & HighScores(i).Value)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub AddEntry(ByVal E As ScoreEntry)
        HighScores.Add(E)
        HighScores.Sort()
        While HighScores.Count > MaxNumberOfHighScores
            HighScores.RemoveAt(HighScores.Count - 1)
        End While
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class ScoreEntry
    Implements IComparable(Of ScoreEntry)

    Public Name As String
    Public Value As Integer

    Public Function CompareTo(other As ScoreEntry) As Integer Implements System.IComparable(Of ScoreEntry).CompareTo
        Return other.Value.CompareTo(Me.Value) ' Sort Descending
    End Function

End Class
```